# Swift optional binding constant names

Tags: swift, optional-binding

I am just transitioning from Objective-C to Swift and have been constantly writing the following code for optional binding,

```
if let tempX = X {

}
```

My question is I have to do it so often that I need to find a new name for constant every time. What's the way to avoid having a new name tempX for every optional X in the code? Wouldn't something like work?

```
if let X = X {

}
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: No, I think it sounds weird. Should I and does it even work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186448/naming-convention-for-optional-binding, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708986/unwrapping-swift-optional-without-variable-reassignment

Comment: Ok that answers the question.

Comment: Also recommended in this style guide: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#optionals (but probably not everybody agrees about that)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can reuse the same identifier in such bindings. But keep in mind that the redefined, non-optional`X` will only be visible inside the `if` scope.

But if you use a `guard` statement, the new `X` may *shadow* the previous variable (i.e., if previous variable was defined in another scope; otherwise will trigger a compiler error). Some would say this could hurt your code readability.

For further information, please see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854162/when-did-guard-let-foo-foo-become-legal).

Comment: With `guard` it may not work.  It depends if the variable was defined in this scope or another.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40353663/1630618

Comment: @vacawama Good catch! Answer improved ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The new constant is only defined within the scope of your if let, so as soon as the scope is over, your tempX is gone. That also means that you can reuse names within the if let scope.

```
if let X = X {

}
```